# How query only number of records in SERVICE-NOW

Tags: python, web-services, soap, suds, servicenow

I want to query to get only number of records and not all objects.

Im doing it:

```
    """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://www.service-now.com/incident" 
        xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
        <ns1:Body>
            <ns0:getRecords>
                <ns0:__limit>100</ns0:__limit>
            </ns0:getRecords>
        </ns1:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But it return all objects limiting 100 and stay slow, for a better performance I think if return only number of records it gets better.

Has any way?

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin called Aggregate Web Service that allows you to query using an aggregate function (e.g. SUM, COUNT, AVG, ...).
Please refer to the following link for more info:
http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Direct_Web_Service_API_Functions#aggregate

The following is a sample SOAP request using the COUNT aggregate function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
   xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:m="http://www.service-now.com"
   xmlns:tns="http://www.service-now.com/map"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <aggregate>
            <COUNT>number</COUNT>
            <active>true</active>
        </aggregate>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use getKeys method with no query filters and it will return all records, just grab the count property from the response.